# How to make the variable global in this case?

Tags: javascript

I am displaying yesterdays date with the help of this below code , all this works fine , but my requirement is that i need to display the variable **yesterday**  as global , because i want to use that variable for other purposes also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayDate()
{
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
var curr_date = d.getDate(); 
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var yesterday = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
alert('The value after modifications is'+yesterday )
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">New Modifications FOR Click Button to Display Yesterday Date</p>
<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me how can i display the variable yesterdayday  as global in this example , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple. like this :

```
var yesterday;
function displayDate()
 {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    var curr_date = d.getDate(); 
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    yesterday = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
    alert('The value after modifications is'+yesterday )
 }
```

You should read some tutorials about JS in general though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var yesterday;
function displayDate()
{
...........
}
</script>
```

**FYI:** by having prefix `var` makes variable global.

Refer to some javascript tutorials

Comment: "by having prefix var makes variable global" - that is misleading and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways.

You can keep from declaring it as a variable inside the function. Then it will be created as a global variable when you use it:

```
function displayDate()
{
...
  yesterday = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
...
}
```

A way that shows the intention more clearly, is to declare it as a variable outside the function:

```
var yesterday;

function displayDate()
{
...
  yesterday = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
...
}
```

For completeness, I want to mention a third possible way. You can also create it as a property of the `window` object. As that is the global scope, the property works as a global variable in almost all aspects:

```
function displayDate()
{
...
  window.yesterday = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
...
}
```

Comment: Except the first is invalid in strict mode. Maybe use `window.yesterday = ...` instead?

Comment: @Ian: Yes, but it doesn't look like the op is using strict mode. Anyhow, I already added the option of using a `window` property instead of a global variable.

Comment: Absolutely, I just thought I'd point that out (wasn't trying to yell at you or anything). I thought using `window` would be a safer, all-around way of doing it, since it would work in both strict and non-strict modes

Answer (score 0):

You can even complicate it but in a nice way I think:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function getYesterDay(values)
{
    if(values)
        getYesterDay.date = values;
    else
        return getYesterDay.date;
}
function displayDate()
{
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    var curr_date = d.getDate(); 
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    getYesterDay(curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date);
    alert('The value after modifications is'+getYesterDay() )
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">New Modifications FOR Click Button to Display Yesterday Date</p>
<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Use getYesterDay() function to set or get date everywhere you want.